# What creates the difference between countries relative price in living price

Tags: living-cost

For example UK and HK. I want to know why in UK they have relative higher income(10 pound) and higher living price(8 pound for a clean lunch).

While HK have relative lower income (5 pound)and lower living price (5 pound for a lunch).

What creates such difference.